# attach every div to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know a DIV can be attached to a Javascript variable with code like this:

```
var targetDiv = jQuery('#targetDiv');
```

However, I am looking for a way to attach ALL the DIVs or ones of a certain class to Javascript variables.

So, if I have the following elements:

```
<div id='bozo'>
<div id='ranger'>
<div id='smokey'>
```

I will end up with the variables:

```
bozo
ranger
smokey
```

I've been building lots of jQuery apps and they often have many divs that need to be kept track of in my code. I want to find an easier way to get control of these divs than assigning them to variables at the beginning of my app.

Either a jQuery or Javascript solution would be fine.

Comment: There are many ways to address your question, depending on what you're trying to achieve in your code. As it stands our question is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most effective way would be to use a JavaScript object.

```
var divs = {};
$("div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') !== undefined) {
        divs[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this);
    }
});
```

With your current HTML, the divs could then be accessed like so:

```
divs["bozo"].show(0);
divs["ranger"]show(0);
divs["smokey"].show(0);
```

You can't name the JavaScript variables directly after the div IDs, because they have different naming conventions. For example, `test-div` is a valid ID for an HTML element, but [not for a JavaScript variable](http://mothereff.in/js-variables#test-div).

However, if an ID just so happens to be a valid JavaScript variable name, then it can be accessed as a mnemonic property of the object:

```
divs.bozo.show(0);
divs.ranger.hide(0);
```

[**See this demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/enp9X/)

**Edit:** Added functionality to detect when the `div` has no ID, based on suggestions from icktoofay and ABFORCE.

Comment: You might want to avoid setting `divs.undefined` when some `div` on the page lacks an ID.

Comment: Are you sure all divs have a id property?

Answer (score 1):

You can "...access those variables without executing any code, as browsers put elements with an id attribute into the global scope on their own."  According to Blender's findings in the comment below.  So one can access those variables by the div's IDs as demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xhWwH/2

EDIT: Kept my previous answer for reference purpose.

Although I do not agree with this type of programming (very unsafe!!!!).  I believe this is what you are looking for:  http://jsfiddle.net/haoudoin/xhWwH/

```
   $("div").each(function(index) {
       console.log(this.id);
       eval("" +this.id + "=this;");
   });

   console.log("creates: " + bozo);
   console.log("creates: " + ranger);
   console.log("creates: " + smokey);
   // reference to your div
   alert(bozo.id);;
```

Comment: Not really. `bozo` is actually `window.bozo`, which is set by the browser, not by your code.

Comment: Could you please confirm you've checked the JSFiddle with your console open?  Tried this in Chrome and IE, works as intended...

Comment: It works, but not because of your code. Remove your code and just leave in the `console.log()`s.

Comment: This is to answer the Op's question... he clearly askes: if he had that set of divs, then he should have those var's created...

Comment: No, no. Your code doesn't actually *do* anything: http://jsfiddle.net/xhWwH/2/. Look at the console and notice that the element still show up.

Comment: What do you mean? That's not my fiddle...  You need to execute that code in order to register those variable names into the window scope.   If the Op executes the jQuery snippet at the start of his app, like he asked, he will have those variables and is able to refer to them by their names, like bozo.id. Demonstrated in this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/haoudoin/xhWwH/1/  By your logic, you're saying that he should be able to use those vars without executing ANY code...

Comment: I'm not sure how many times I have to explain it. Your jQuery snippet isn't actually doing anything. `$("<div>")` *creates* a `div` element. It doesn't look for one. Browsers automatically make elements with `id`s available in the global scope, which is why my empty fiddle still works.

Comment: Exactly. He *can* access those variables without executing any code, as browsers put elements with an `id` attribute into the global scope on their own. Just try it.

Comment: You still need to change `$(this).id` to `this.id`.

Comment: Ahh.. thanks for correcting my rusty jQuery skills... updated all, if you down voted, please change? :)

Comment: I am interested why you consider the technique you posted as, 'unsafe'.

Comment: If he ever imports another library that defines a var that happens to be the same name as another var he tries to access, using the above method, he would get a collision.  jQuery.noConflict() was born for similar reasons.  http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to assign every jQuery object to a javascript variable/object. Because the jQuery syntax is very very easy to use.
You can refer to a html element so easy with jQuery, like this:

```
$("div") // all div elements
$("div#foo") // div with id="foo"
$(".foo") // all element which have 'foo' class
```

However if your want to assign to a JS object use this:

```
var obj = new Object() // or = {};
$("div[id]").each(function(){
    obj[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this);
});
```

Comment: You are correct, the jQuery syntax is easy. However, I often have to control DIVS in multiple areas of the app. From my understanding, when you use jQuery('.class') more than a couple of times, you should assign it to a variable because of the processing time used each time you use jQuery(). So, I would like to just assign it once when the app starts and be finished with it.